# Error when creat new database in FlameRobin, I/O error during "open" operation for files

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5, flamerobin

I'm trying to creat a new database in FlameRobin with Window OS, but when i creat, FlameRobin show error:

```
*** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Database:Create
Message: isc_dsql_execute_immediate failed
SQL Message : -902
Unsuccessful execution caused by a system error that
precludes successful execution of subsequent statements
Engine Code : 335544344
Engine Message :
1/0 error during "open" operation for file
"localhost:D:\Document\Ortems\DELMIA Ortems - SCPO -
  Scheduling - Demonstrate level 1\Firebird
  Databases\APSO3_MECA_MP_SRP.GDB
database or file exists
```

I also try to fix follow this link [Firebird Error while trying to create file, Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942639/firebird-error-while-trying-to-create-file-permission-denied) , but it can not change.

I also grant full control for user requires.

Comment: You say you have 'grant full control for user requires', but who exactly has read and write rights to this file? You are connecting through a Firebird server process, and if that is running as a service, then the user running the service (the local system account by default) will need to have sufficient access.

Comment: That is not "creating NEW database" - the error text says outright: `file exists`. Change the name of the file to be created so it would really be a NEW database, not one already existing. Also, i have doubts you copied all the error text verbatim: there is an opening quote mark in `...for file "localhost:D....` - but there is no matching closing quote mark.